# Uploading files with php issue

Tags: php

```
  <?php
  if(!isset($_POST["submit"]))
   {echo "Sorry,there was an error";}
 else
 {      $f1=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$path="web/";
$file=$path.$f1;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"],$file);
```

This does not upload file ,can someone see whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"],$file);
```

to

```
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$file);
```

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file` requires the first parameter be the `temporary file name` not the `name`. Try with -

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["temp_name"], $file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"][""tmp_name"],$file);
```

System never knows about file name. If system ready to upload your file, it will  go to temp folder. If you use `tmp_name` System knows whats your file to be uploaded.